# jQuery File Upload, limit files to 1 image and 1 video?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, uploading

I am attempting to use this jQuery plugin for uploading files http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

I want to be able to limit the files a user can upload to only 1 image and 1 video. I know I could set the form to only allow jpg, gif, png, mov and mp4 files but this would not stop somebody from uploading 2 images or 2 videos. Is there a way to limit it to 1 image and 1 video?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum number of files, uploadable at once to be 2, inside `php.ini`.
So if you want to limit it per user, you can do it in the backend.

Check for the extension from the php layer. also provide some `User Context` before you  upload (`AJAX POST` can do), process in the backend to know if user has already done his/her uploads. Based on the value of response, you can upload the file in callback.

A frontend processing, could be some kind of page level `ACL`, that can be initialized at time of page loading based on user information, and allowing or disallowing him from uploading but you need some kind of invalidation for this cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add one upload field per each type, and then set this values:

```
limitConcurrentUploads
```

To limit the number of concurrent uploads, set this option to an integer value greater than 0.

```
Type: number
Default: undefined
Example: 3


maxNumberOfFiles
```

This option limits the number of files that are allowed to be uploaded using this widget.
By default, unlimited file uploads are allowed.

```
Type: number
Example: 10
```

[Source](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)